# How to add my shopify store search to a external campaign website

Tags: html, search, shopify

So at the moment I'm creating an external campaign website and want to hook up my Shopify search input to the campaign site - so that when someone adds a keyword to the search on the campaign site it will direct them to the Shopify site with listed keyword products.

Is there a clear and simple way to implement this?

thanks,
Manny

Comment: I think in your case you can use Shopify JavaScript Buy SDK. http://shopify.github.io/js-buy-sdk/api/classes/ShopClient.html#method-fetchQueryProducts

Comment: So when someone lands on the campaign page I want them to fill the input with a keyword "Gothic" and then when they click on search they are directed to the Shopify store website filtered search page where all the gothic merch with be listed out. - I don't want the campaign page to list out any merch from the store

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be enough just to send form to
`yourshopifydomain.com/search?q=Gothick`

```
<html>
  <body>

    <form action="http://yourshopifydomain.com/search">
      Search: <input type="text" name="q" value="Gothick"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```